# Download a torrent with php

Tags: php, download, bittorrent

I want to download a torrent using php.

So the scenario is that the user uploads a torrent and the server downloads it.
Than the user can download the torrent using his browser.

Comment: There are many torrent clients... why not just spawn off one of those?  uTorrent has a remote option, does it not?  Write code to act as its remote.  Then, use FFMPEG to convert media to the format you need.  Also, please only use this for legal purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if this is the right way for you but:

- Install rtorrent (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/RTorrent)
- configure rtorrent to watch a direcory for new torrent-files (http://jkt.im/2011/09/28/automatic-torrent-management-with-rtorrent-and-some-helper-scripts/)
- rtorrent will download the files and move it into a directory like "done"
- php script checks the folder vor new content and convert / show the files online in webpage

Comment: if i want it to write in opt/lampp/httpdocs should i just start it up with a sudo comand.

Comment: You can start rtorrent with an normal user and give him write access to /opt/lampp/httdocs or put it into the www-data/apache group

Answer (score -1):

All the functionality you need already exist with `rTWi` http://rtwi.jmk.hu/ and its also open source so all you need is little customization